# Resizing cells to fit labels, has set image size and label has some rounded corners

Tags: ios, swift

i am trying to get a cell to resize to the text/or image inside it. But also the labels have some rounded corners depending on their position. I have tried using snippets like:

```
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect:cell.receivedText!.bounds, byRoundingCorners:[.TopRight, .BottomLeft, .BottomRight], cornerRadii: CGSizeMake(30, 30))
    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.path = path.CGPath
    cell.receivedText!.layer.mask = maskLayer
```

and

```
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

but i cant get the two to work in conjunction.

Here is my current code minus snippets that didnt work:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    createConversation()
    let cell: ConversationCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ConversationCell") as! ConversationCell

    if conversation.conversationArray[indexPath.row].isAReceivedMessage == true {
        cell.receivedText!.text = conversation.conversationArray[indexPath.row].text
        cell.receivedText!.textAlignment = .Left
        cell.receivedText!.sizeToFit()
        cell.receivedProfileImage!.image = self.conversationProfileImage!.image
        cell.receivedText!.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 44/255, green: 99/255, blue: 105/255, alpha: 5/100)

    } else {
        cell.sentText!.text = conversation.conversationArray[indexPath.row].text
        cell.sentText!.textAlignment = .Right
        cell.sentText!.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 204/255, green: 115/255, blue: 115/255, alpha: 1)
        cell.sentText!.sizeToFit()
    }

    return cell
}
```

This is what im trying to achieve

[image: This is what im trying to achieve]

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Did you figure a solution for this? I am running into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

> but i cant get the two to work in conjunction.

There are two problems:

- Timing. When a view is resized, its mask is not resized. Thus, if you attach the mask before you know the final size of the view, you will get the wrong answer.
- Resuse. Don't forget that a cell is reused. Thus, in `cellForRow`, you always need to remove the existing mask if there is one, because you're doing to be making another one to fit the new resized cell.

Comment: Care to elaborate more? I am not sure how remove an existing mask. Doing so leads to crashes for me.

Comment: @AndyM If you have a question, please ask it as _question_.

Comment: how do you remove a mask if there is one?

Comment: @AndyM Not in a comment, please. As a _question_. Click the Ask Question link in the top right of the page and ask your question. Show what you're trying to do, how you're crashing, etc. This discussion is not appropriate for comments.