# Resize UITableViewCell to fit label or image and rounded corners

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview

I am attaching a [sample project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bl4x51uqes20uol/DynamicHeightImage.zip?dl=0) to allow you to test and see what I can do to fix this.

I am trying to resize the height's image dynamically and at the same time round two corners on every other cell. Doing so results in a mask that is cut off.

Basically here is what I am trying to achieve:

1. UITableView's row height is set to automatic.

   ```
   _nTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
   _nTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 150;
   ```
2. Download images using SDWebImage library using a CustomTableViewCell

   ```
   [self.nImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl] completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL){}];
   ```
3. Configure a cell to round the corners depending on its row

   ```
   UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath
                         bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.bubbleView.bounds
                         byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerTopLeft)
                         cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(20, 20)];

   CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];

   maskLayer.frame = self.bubbleView.bounds;
   maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;

   self.bubbleView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
   ```

Doing the above results in a mask being ***cut off*** but the height is calculated correctly. See below:
[image]

Based on this [stack overflow's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39396501/resizing-cells-to-fit-labels-has-set-image-size-and-label-has-some-rounded-corn), we need to remove the mask if there is one. I have tried to set the mask to nil in awakeFromNib method but that has no affect.

```
self.nImageView.layer.mask = nil;
self.nImageView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
```

I also tried following the answers from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067578/removing-all-calayers-sublayers) but it results in the app crashing.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: are you keeping size of image fixed or variable?

Comment: Grabbed your sample project... yes, it crashes until I remove the "remove layer" code in cellForRowAtIndexPath... but, I can't tell what you are going for. Is the picture you have here what you *want*? If not, how is it supposed to look?

Comment: @DonMag I have updated the project with removing "the layer" code. If you comment [cell configureBubbleInRow:indexPath.row], you will see what I am trying to see. See this: http://imgur.com/a/JVtA3

Comment: I think you're going to be better off setting the mask (or, re-setting it) in the completion block after the image has downloaded. A little quick playing with it, and it's close - at least, assuming this was is the end goal: http://d.pr/i/Uz7H

Comment: @DonMag I tried calling [self configureBubbleInRow:rowIndex] and it is not giving me similar results as you. Can you tell me what did you do?

Comment: @AndyM - I played around with a few more things... not sure it'll give you exactly what you are going for - and ***no guarantees***, but worth a look. See my added answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible solution - may not be the best, may not do exactly what you need, but might get you on your way...

Instead of trying to manipulate the layers / masks from within your custom UITableViewCell class, use a UIView subclass as the image holder. The code of that class can handle the rounded corners and layer/mask size updating.

See example here: https://github.com/DonMag/dhImage

Answer (score -1):

To set height of row based on it's content:

```
  - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {

    if(/*check if content is text label*/)
    {
      UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell1"];
      UILabel *lbl = (UILabel*)[ cell.contentView viewWithTag:1000];  
      lbl.text = message;
      [cell layoutIfNeeded];
      CGSize size = [cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];

      if(size.height < 100) {
            return  100;
      }
      else {
           return size.height;
      }
    }
    else {                 // content is image 
        return 200;
      }
    }
```

Configure a cell to round the corners:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  .
  .
  .
    [cell.contentView.layer setCornerRadius:10.0f];
  return cell;
}
```

To Download images using SDWebImage library:

```
      SDWebImageDownloader *downloader = [SDWebImageDownloader sharedDownloader];
       [downloader downloadImageWithURL:addr 
                                options:0 
                               progress:
                  ^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize) {
                        // progression tracking code 
                              }
                              completed:^(UIImage *image, NSData *data, NSError *error, BOOL finished) {
                      if (image && finished) {
                          // Pass the imageView to this block
                          // After completion display downloaded image in imageView
                          imageView.image = image;
                      }
                  }];
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Hope it helps!! reply back @AndyM

Comment: there was a crash because of removing the layer in cellForRowAtIndexPath but you didn't mention also your changing the variable names for no reason

Comment: which part? @zombie

Comment: Actually i have working code.. i have pasted some part of it!! @zombie. if  you see any change please notify me.. will be happy know n change :)

Comment: This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread after the engine was accessed from the main thread. This can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.

Comment: @nikdange_me Thank you but this doesn't use UITableViewAutomaticDimension. I have it working when I have a static height whether it was for a label or image.